# how to compare spreadsheet rows and columns with database table rows and columns

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a spreadsheet in my local machine with columns(employee number and salary). I need to update employee table with this value. Mismatched rows has to be tabled in browser.

Using file upload control in visual studio .net I'm uploading excel sheet. When clicking on the button I need unmatched rows.

I think we can achieve this by using datasets to bring database values and compare with sheet, but what is the best way to compare?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it:

First, you should have atleast a 'comparison column' in each of your datasets (ie. Excel Sheet and Database table).

You will create 2 objects to hold the data for the excel sheet and the  table records.
You will then populate them.

Next is where you will have a little magic. You will have to make a choice of which of the two is you primary dataset.

What next? .... loop through items.
Pseudo:

```
DataSet ds1 = .....;
DataSet ds2 = .....;

foreach record(r) in ds1 Table
    foreach record(s) in ds2 Table
        if record r = record s
            store this as matched record and break
        else
            store this as mismached record (may need some more logic here)
    endloop
endloop
```

Unfortunately I do not have a copy/paste function/method to do this but can provide guidance.
Hope this gives you a starting point.